# save sheet pdf excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following vba codes

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
Dim FileAndLocation As Variant
Dim strPathLocation As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strPathFile As String

strPathLocation = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
strFilename = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value
strPathFile = strPathLocation & strFilename
Sheets("Sheet2").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
strPathLocation & strFilename & ".pdf" _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

what i want to achieve is to save Sheet2 as pdf to the specified path and specified file name

Comment: What is the problem / error? Is there a path separator on the the end of `strPathLocation`?

Comment: i am getting run time error, when i debug  Sheet2 to end of vba is highlighted yellow

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: run time error-2147024773(8007007b).Document not saved

Comment: Make sure to `Debug.Print strPathLocation & strFilename & "pdf"` - most likely it's missing a path separator.

Comment: ok will check and revert thanks

Comment: i have changed my vba as follows and the pdf is saved but not the exact location  Sub DesktopPDF()
 
 fPath = Range("A2").Value

    fName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")


    Sheets("Sheet2").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=fName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
End Sub

Comment: You didn't include `fPath` - you only have `FileName:=fName`. Most likely should be `FileName:=fPath & Application.PathSeparator & fName`.

Comment: i have added  fpath .My target folder is C:\Users\rakesh\Desktop\lease and my file name is named checklist when i execute vba , the file is saved as pdf but in another folder C:\Users\rakesh\Documents\leasechecklist must be saved in folder as as follows C:\Users\rakesh\Desktop\lease\checklist

Comment: You haven't added the `Application.PathSeparator` then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that.

Select in vba your sheet and use this function to export, the filename you could pass as a parameter in the function.

```
Sub ExportarPDF()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="yourpath.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```